# Re-mount volume in a running container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, boot2docker, docker-volume

For development purposes I'm using docker compose in a VirtualBox running in OSX. To start the magic I run something like this (`dkc=docker-compose`)

```
$ dkc -f base.yml -f development.yml up -d --build
```

My docker compose files would be something like this:

**base.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  padeltotal-app:
    build:
      context: ./padeltotal
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.app
    container_name: 'padeltotal-app'
    links:
      - padeltotal-mysql:db
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"

  padeltotal-mysql:
    build:
      context: ./padeltotal
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.db
    container_name: 'padeltotal-mysql'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  nginx-lt:
    extends:
      file: common.yml
      service: nginx
    volumes_from:
      - padeltotal-app
```

**development:**

```
version: '2'
services:
  padeltotal-app:
    volumes:
      - ./padeltotal/code/src:/var/www/padeltotal/src
```

It's a PHP+MySql application

While I'm developing I'd like to have the volume with the PHP code I've mounted updated reflecting the changes from my `./padeltotal` folder.

The default behaviour of the mounted volumen should be to reflect the HOST folder. However, in OSX is not working that way

I repeat, it's for development purposes, for production mode I don't even use docker compose

Is there a way to re-mount the volume?

What would be a different approach?

Comment: What do you mean by "update in real time"?  The mount is a view into the underlying filesystem - changes will be reflected inside the container.

Comment: Do you mean you want to reuse your mysql-volume? So e.g. creating a user which is saved in mysql and deleting your containers serveral times and reexecuting docker-compose but still have that user inside your new mysql container?

Comment: Sorry, didn't properly ask the question. Will edit it

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "re-mount", generally any networking would need to be set up when the environment is created. What are you using to manage VirtualBox? To see the data there, you would need to make sure you have the Mac networked to the VB directories you are using for Docker volumes. If it's just for dev purposes, you could try the Docker Beta app for Mac, in which you can adjust settings for network shares.